# How to make sure a file exists or can be created before writing to it in Python?

Tags: python, file-io, filesystems

I'm writing a function and I want it to `touch` a file so that I can write to that file. If the file doesn't exist, I will get an error. How can I say that?

Comment: The [open()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open) documentation may be interesting to look at.

Comment: What you have described is not the purpose of `touch`

Comment: `touch` will update the timestamp of an existing file, or create a new file if it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Daenyth sorry. What's the purpose then?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implement touch using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158076/implement-touch-using-python)

Comment: @SilentGhost: I think it's only a duplicate if you take this at face value. It's really an XY problem, so the dupe doesn't actually help the main issue.

Comment: @SilentGhost: He doesn't know how to handle IOError in this context

Comment: @SilentGhost You're right. I didn't. The question is more or less a duplicate, but the OP in the one you linked to does not have the same exact issue as me, so it's not an exact duplicate. He's looking at it from a more abstracted perspective, and I'm just a newbie grappling with open(file, readmethod)

Comment: Very misleading title! As others have suggested, this is not what `touch` does. You might want to consider to rephrase this!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just open the file for writing and it will be created if it doesn't exist (assuming you have proper permission to write to that location).

```
f = open('some_file_that_might_not_exist.txt', 'w')
f.write(data)
```

You will get an `IOError` if you can't open the file for writing.

Comment: Note, this is the correct answer to the question detailed, but this is not a "Python equivalent of touch" (as the question title may imply)

Comment: For those innocently looking for a Python implementation of `touch`, note the above is not comparable to unix `touch` because ***USING THE `w` OPTION WILL DELETE THE CONTENTS OF THE FILE IF IT ALREADY EXISTS***.  `touch` only changes timestamps if the file already exists.  For a Python implementation of `touch`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158076/implement-touch-using-python.

Answer (score 7):

Per [the docs, os.utime()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.utime) will function similar to touch if you give it None as the time argument, for example:

```
os.utime("test_file", None)
```

When I tested this (on Linux and later Windows), I found that test_file had to already exist.  YMMV on other OS's.

Of course, this doesn't really address writing to the file.  As other answers have said, you usually want [open](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) for that and [try ... except](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) for catching exceptions when the file does not exist.

Comment: Here is a version that addresses the "file must exist" issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158076/implement-touch-using-python

Answer (score 0):

if you actually want to raise an error if the file doesn't exist, you can use

```
import os
if not os.access('file'):
    #raise error
f = open('file')
#etc.
```

Comment: I will definitely eventually use this. Thank you.

Comment: Note that the file might become inaccessible between the call to `os.access` and the call to `open`.

Comment: @Brian, so generally it's better to just use `try` & `except IOError`?

Comment: @Tim McNamara: It's always better, as it can always happen no matter how many checks you do beforehand.