# How to touch a file to a certain datetime in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

In Linux, I can change the creation date of a file using [touch](https://askubuntu.com/a/711243/55365):

```
touch -a -m -t 201512180130.09 file.txt
```

In Python, I can use the touch command to change the creation date, but I don't see any arguments to set it to a different date than the current one.

```
from pathlib import Path
Path('path/to/file.txt').touch()
```

**How can I set the date in Python?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158076/implement-touch-using-python

Comment: Why on earth was this downvoted? @ShravanYadav: The question you linked to is just about touching a file, not about setting a timestamp.

Comment: I have not downvoted it. Why should I downvote and put an answer to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also call the touch command in python

```
from subprocess import call
call(["touch","-a","-m","-t","201512180130.09","file.txt"])
```

Comment: sorry there is already answer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158076/implement-touch-using-python

Comment: This is not a cross-platform solution, and you've linked to a question, not an answer. The question isn't even the same; it's just about touching, not changing a file's timestamp.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`os.utime`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.html#os.utime) to set the access and modified times of a file.