# IN PYTHON: What type of data structure is this and how can I save it to a file?

Tags: python, data-structures, dataset

What type of data structure is this and how can I write it to a file?

```
    import datetime

    now = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z")
    temp = 23
    humidity = 35

    data = '[{{ "timestamp": "{0}", "temperature": "{1:0.1f}", "humidity": "{2:0.1f}" }}]'.format(now, temp, humidity)
```

Thanks.

Comment: your code is *incomplete*.

Comment: It is not a datastructure rather it's way to format strings in python, https://stackoverflow.com/a/517471/4985099

Comment: Like @Sushanth said, it's not a data structure. It's timestamp formated to string, then put together with other values. To put this data in file you can use this code snippet: 
`text_file = open("file.txt", "w")`
`text_file.write(data)`
`text_file.close()`
Also to learn more about basic python, try [this interactive Python 3 course](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-python-3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a string, as @Sushanth said:

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
temp=2.2341
humidity=2.123123
data = '[{{ "timestamp": "{0}", "temperature": "{1:0.1f}", "humidity": "{2:0.1f}" }}]'.format(now, temp, humidity)
print(data)
>>>[{ "timestamp": "2020-06-10 08:24:04.704800", "temperature": "2.2", "humidity": "2.1" }]

print(type(data))
>>><class 'str'>
```

Just it is created with `format` which allows us to insert a specified value(s) inside the string's placeholder. And, to write this **string** into a file, you can try this:

```
text_file = open("sample.txt", "w")
n = text_file.write(data)
text_file.close()
```

And if you want to create a new file with this variable `data`, you can checkout this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158076/implement-touch-using-python), and then open,write and close the file, as I showed you before.