# if first time today then do X

Tags: python, opencv, if-statement

i'm working on a project with computer vision on a raspberry pi where I can't get my head around how to solve the folloing problem:

i need a script where if it's the first time today that it detects my face then it needs to do something otherwise if it's not the first time today that it discovers my face then do nothing.
i have the script for face detection but my problem is that I don't know how to write the code for the function if its the first time today that it detects my face then do X otherwise Y

Comment: Can you think of a way to remember whether or not the program has seen your face earlier today? (Hint: can you think of a way to remember whether the program has seen your face *at all*? Can you think of a way for the program to tell when the day changes? When the day changes, what should happen to the remembered data, to make it work the way you want?)

Comment: can you think of a way to remember whether the program has seen your face at all

yes i would create a variable and set it to TRUE if it detects my face, but i don't know how to reset the variable when the day shifts, thats my main problem

Comment: Do you know how to find out what day it is? Then, check what day it is, and see if it's the same day as last time you checked.

Comment: You could find the path to your script and check its modification date. If it isn't today, `touch` your own script and assume it's the first detection of the day... https://stackoverflow.com/a/34603829/2836621

Comment: Thank you for simplifying my problem @Karl Knechtel. I figured it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your help @Karl Knechtel i figured it out.. it was much more simple then i thought.

```
import datetime
First=True
Dato=''
if Dato!=datetime.date.today():
    print('first time today')
    Dato=datetime.date.today()
```