# File not found in a created directory

Tags: python, mkdir, python-os

I am working to add a file in temporary folder like so:

```
self._dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
self._dir = os.path.join(self._dir, "test")
os.mkdir(self._dir)
self.checkpoint = os.path.join(self._dir, "file.txt")
```

So the above in the init function.

and when I call my main function, I only see the test folder and there is no file.txt along with it.

how can i solve this?

Comment: no sorry, i have edited my post, it is due to copy-paste

Comment: put a print so you can see the content of your variables.  Are you making a temporal folder in an absolute or relative path. And if it's a relative path, relative to what (from which folder are you executing the script?) printing the value of the folder will help you understand what is being done

Comment: Where do you create `file.txt`? You create two directories but no file.

Comment: the content of my variable is `self._dir` is `tmp/temp475/test`

Comment: `os.path.join(self._dir, "file.txt")` does not create a file, it joins the two filepaths together. you still need to create the file. try: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-an-empty-file-using-python/

Answer (score 3):

Another option to go with the other answers is to use the built-in [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module and the [`touch()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.touch) function (as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34603829/1862861)), e.g.,

```py
from pathlib import Path

...

self._dir = Path(tempfile.mkdtemp())
self._dir = self._dir / "test"
self._dir.mkdir()
self.checkpoint = self._dir / "file.txt"

# touch, i.e., create the file
self.checkpoint.touch()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not actually created the file, just generated a filepath. Try this.

```
import os

checkpoint = os.path.join('.', "file.txt")

f = open(checkpoint, 'w')
f.close()
```

It will create the file in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you have provided, that is the expected behaviour.

`os.mkdir` creates the directory, but there is no other code to create a text file - `os.path.join` only joins two or more filenames into one combined filename, it doesn't create anything.

If you want to create the text file, you would probably need to add something like

```
f = open(self.checkpoint, "w") #create a new blank file
f.close() #close it so we're not leaving the handle open
```

Comment: I'd gone `with open(self.checkpoint, r'w'): pass`

Answer (score 0):

You do not create "file.txt". All you have is a path to a non-existent file.

You also need to make sure you clean up your temporary directory.

```
import tempfile
import shutil
from pathlib import Path

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        # create "test" directory within a temporary directory
        self.temp = Path(tempfile.mkdtemp())
        self._dir = self.temp / "test"
        self._dir.mkdir()
        # create empty "file.txt"
        self.checkpoint = self._dir / "file.txt"
        with open(self.checkpoint, "w"):
            pass
    def __del__(self):
        # don't forget to clean up
        shutil.rmtree(self.temp)
```